# How to register Windows Phone app as handler of url

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When I tap and hold on some link I get this dialog :
[image: Share dialog]
I want to register my own Windows Phone app as handler of url-s so it can appear in this dialog.
I have already looked on file and Uri associations for Windows Phone but I haven't found solution.

Comment: what exactly do you mean ? any example would be great for understanding. Are you getting these option in WP7 ? if yes then let me know so that I can check it on my phone.

Comment: I am creating WP8 application. In WP8 when I open web browser and long hold on some link I get dialog like on picture. I want register my app to appear in that dialog like handler of links.

Comment: Oh I searched with no luck. Obviously its closed source! Might not be available for us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible to register your app to appear in the list of apps when the 'share' option is used, either on Windows Phone 7 or 8.

The nearest thing, which is not what you're looking for, is Uri schemes which allow an app to call another once it's Uri scheme is registered (Windows Phone 8 only).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx